# Views as User Controls or Windows

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am new to this and as such probably being an idiot.  That said, do I want my Views to be UC's or Windows?  I'm guessing it depends on my usage scenario, maybe...

I have a main view that has "buttons" on it for different actions, e.g. CreateThis or ModifyThat.  When the user clicks on one of these "buttons" I want to show an appropriate View in a Dialog type scenario.  This *SEEMS* like it would lend itself to being a Window however I'm not sure how the [Window Manager](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/) factors into this.

Also, when I did Winforms development I made all my "views" UC's that I would embedd in one reusable Window so that they were more flexible, is that something that apply's here?

Anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume WPF since you mention `Window` rather than `ChildWindow`, but generally you want to create `UserControls`.

`WindowManager` automatically ensures that your content is displayed in the appropriate container based on whether you call `ShowPopup`, `ShowDialog` or `ShowNotification` so making them UCs makes things a little more flexible (in fact `WindowManager` sets up the initial window for WPF apps, resolving the view for whichever ViewModel your bootstrapper starts with and ensuring a window is created if the view isn't already a window)

As for composite views, all you need to do is include your sub-view models as properties of a composition container (i.e. another view model which will host them) and bind them using a `ContentControl` and CMs conventions

e.g. the VM that will show 2 UCs would maybe look like:

```
public class SomeCompositeViewModel : Screen
{
    public SomeOtherViewModel SomeOtherView { get; set; } // You probably want INPC here as per usual
    public YetAnotherViewModel YetAnotherView { get; set; } 

    public SomeCompositeViewModel()
    {
         // Setup as you need - direct instantiation, IoC/DI, use MEF, whatever works for you
         SomeOtherView = new SomeOtherViewModel();
         YetAnotherView = new YetAnotherViewModel();

    }
}
```

and the XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeAssembly.Yadda.Yadda.SomeComposititeViewModel">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Bind to SomeOtherViewModel via the SomeOtherView property etc -->
        <ContentControl x:Name="SomeOtherView" /> 
        <ContentControl x:Name="YetAnotherView" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

(be a bit more creative with the layout won't you!)

If you want all the items to have a lifecycle you can just use `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive` but it sounds more like you are looking for composite views, not tool windows

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the Window Manager did so much leg work for me.  Also, I'd award bonus points, if possible, for answering a question I hadn't even thought to ask yet.  Referring to Composite Views of course.  Most Excellent, thanks.  Out of curiosity, what is `Screen` that you are inheriting from?

Comment: `Screen` is CMs default implementation of `IScreen` - an interface that exposes lifecycle functionality such as activation, deactivation, elegant close etc - it also inherits `PropertyChangedBase` which contains INPC functionality. To work with conductors it's best to use the `IScreen` interface as the conductor implementation in CM fishes for the interfaces this implements when conducting windows in order to put them through the proper lifecycle steps (you can just go down the route of implementing IActivate, IDeactivate, IGuardClose etc yourself, but why reinvent the wheel!)

Comment: Oh yeah, and `IViewAware` + view caching is also implemented by `Screen` - those are useful (you can get a ref to the view from the VM if you want to do some manipulation - I'm not saying that you should be manipulating the view as a known type, but maybe you want to write a helper class which fishes the visual tree for a particular type of control in order to make it invisible or something like that)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `Screen`.  I am really enjoying CM but find the lack of Documentation disappointing,  maybe I'm looking in the wrong place but just the partially finished stuff from the CodePlex site is all I've found that's up to date.

Comment: I think the docs on CodePlex site are very good - they walk you through setting it up and pretty much every aspect of the framework - there's a lot to read, but it's all useful. Learning curve is shallow so you can get to grips with it within a couple of weeks